# Filter and show list by user in Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I want to show the user only those lists to which he is subscribed but I can't get to the doc.
Show every list is work good but I don't want to show every list for every user.
Users in doc is an array in doc because one list can be accessed by several.

Look from db:
[image]

my code attemps:

```
const userName = "Arex Speed";
const [myLists, setMyLists] = useState([])

//get all lists - work good
useEffect(() => {
db.collection('lists').onSnapshot(snapshot => (
      setMyLists(
        snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
          id: doc.id, 
          name: doc.data().name,
          users: doc.data().users,
        }))
      )
    ))
},[])
    
//trying filter by where - show epmty
  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection('lists')
    .where("users", "array-contains", "name")
    .where("name", "==", userName)
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => (
      setMyLists(
        snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
          id: doc.id, 
          name: doc.data().name,
          users: doc.data().users,
        }))
      )
    ))
  },[])

//try filter by docs -show empty
  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection('lists')
    .onSnapshot(snapshot => (
      snapshot.docs.fiter(doc => (
        doc.data().users.find(user => 
        user.name === userName && setMyList(prev => 
        [...prev, doc])
        )
      ))
    )
    )
  },[])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe when user clicks to subscribe to a list, write that lists name as a key and lists id as a value into user object. and then user will have all the user he will subscribe to. Then you would map true lists and check if user has that list, you return it.

Comment: Hmm, I will think about this but maybe I write wrong, user can be added to list or create own. F.e I have 2 lists Shopping and Work and I see them, then I can add acces to list Shopping to you and then you will see that list plus lists which you create.